# gathering to read full quran

Tags: dua, quran-recitation, bidah, reading-quran, lying

As Salamu Aleikum
My First question: i am seeking the help of my senior and brothers today concerning gathering to recite the full Quran whereby anyone will be reading a Juz or two.
I recently heard that is somehow an inovation (bida'a) so i have been thinking about a lot because i do give myself to such event that we hold every
friday morning and when one of us is in need of help, so i went online to make some researches concerning this topic and i almost all the islamic platforms
i've visited say that the way we've been doing it is an inivation in a way. So i have this strong doubt about it since then and i couldn't ask my imam because
we practice it at his house and most of the imam and big sheikhs in our erea practice it so my only solution was the internet and i'm still learning arabic
i have not reach a level where i will start learning the hadiths and the Fiqr.
My second question is since i am having a strong doubt i wanted to come up with lie so that i could escape in the participation of such event...
PLEASE I AM A BTROTHER IS DISTRESS, I WOULD SERIOUSLY BE GLAD TO HEAR FROM AS SOON AS POSSIBLE

Comment: can you explain what's your question please? I didn't really understand

Comment: Why should this be bid'ah?

Comment: @Medi1Saif i have not said that it is bid'ah, but i rather said i heard it's bid'ah and i need the help of somone more knowlegeable to kindly come in help